# Clicking HTML Button and Create a File

Tags: html, web

Can someone helps me, i need to make a button when it Clicked, will creating a file in my storage

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<body style="text-align:center;">
    <h1 style="color:green;">  
            Create Your First Account 
    </h1>
    Name:<input type="text" id="username" value="Jack">
    <p>
        Password:<input type="password" id="password" value="some password">
    </p>
    <p>
    <button type="button" onclick="createNow()">Create Your First Account</button>
    </p>
    <p href="admin_mode.html">
      <button>Admin Mode</button>
    </p>

    <script>
    var fs = require('fs')
    function createNow() {
        var userinput = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var passwordinput = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var content = `{ "username": "${userinput}, "password": "${passwordinput} "}`
       //Create user acc
        fs.writeFileSync(`./database/registeredUser/${userinput}.json`, content)
        <a href="home.html">
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

i've put a `fs.writeFileSync` there and when someone click the button, its not creating the file and contents

Comment: Hit `F12` and check your console for errors. Are you using node.js?

Comment: yes nodejs, no error showen on terminal

Answer (score 0):

You should use **a.href="home.html"**

```
   function createNow() {
        var userinput = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var passwordinput = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var content = `{ "username": "${userinput}, "password": "${passwordinput} "}`
       //Create user acc
        fs.writeFileSync(`./database/registeredUser/${userinput}.json`, content);
        a.href="home.html"; 
    }
```